# windows batch file 7 zip archive files using date range

Tags: windows, backup, 7-zip, timestamp

I am currently running a batch file that backs up all my files created or modified within the past 24 hours using an old version of Winzip.  I use 7 zip for a lot of archiving and would like to be able to use it for this purpose but it does not have switches that let you select files based on their date/time stamp.  I do NOT want to copy files to a directory based on their time stamp and archive them form there.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

and

http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples  ->

```
 forfiles  /c "7za a -t7z @fname.7z @file" /d -1
```

Comment: Mind expanding these links? Link only answers may be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Wth some research I came up with something that should work...

```
forfiles  /c "cmd /c 7z u -t7z [setup an empty 7z file].7z @path" /d -1 /s
```

Answer (score 0):

Close but will archive files older than one day with those switches here is the syntax for current day (with a date added to the output file :

```
set hr=%time:~0,2%
if "%hr:~0,1%" equ " " set hr=0%hr:~1,1%

Rem  - compress data that is from current day

forfiles /p "c:\<path of what to backup>" /d 0 /c "cmd /c C:\<Location of 7zip>\7za u -tzip D:\<Where you want archive saved>\Archive_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.zip @PATH -mmt"
```